# If $u(x,t)$ satisfies the heat equation then so does its conjugate.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, heat-equation

Assume that $u$ satisfies the heat equation:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}.$$

Then why does the conjugate of $u$ also satisfy the equation, i.e., 
$$\partial_t \bar{u}=\partial_x^2 \bar{u}.$$

This identity is used in the proof of the uniqueness of the solution given in Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis. I attached the excerpt below, but I don't know how to show that the equation holds for the conjugate as well. I would greatly appreciate any explanations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, $u = \text{Re}(u) + i\text{Im}(u)$, and if $u$ satisfies the heat equation, then both $\text{Re}(u)$ and $\text{Im}(u)$ satisfy the heat equation as well.